# How do I optimize this IRremote code?

Tags: code-optimization

I am using a [ATTINY85 Digispark](http://digistump.com/products/1) board with an [IR receiver](https://storage.googleapis.com/baudaeletronicadatasheet/TSOP48.pdf) to light some LEDs in my project. The Digispark has a limitation that does not allow it to use the [IRremote.h library](https://github.com/Arduino-IRremote/Arduino-IRremote). I know that there a series of workarounds for that ([including a tiny_IRremote library](https://gist.github.com/SeeJayDee/caa9b5cc29246df44e45b8e7d1b1cdc5)), but I decided to use this simple code I have found online. It turns on/off a led according to a button press in my Remote:

```
#define led_pin 9
#define receive_pin 4

bool led_state = LOW;  
unsigned long int remote_button_code = 835585799;

void setup() {

  pinMode(receive_pin, INPUT);
  pinMode(led_pin,OUTPUT);
  switch_state = digitalRead(switch_pin);

}

unsigned long int receiveIR() {
  // Wait for start pulse
  while(digitalRead(receive_pin) != LOW)

  if(pulseIn(receive_pin, HIGH, 20000) == 0) return 0;

  // Receive pulses
  unsigned long int result = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    int pulseLength = pulseIn(receive_pin, HIGH, 5000);
    if(pulseLength == 0) return 0;
    if(pulseLength > 1000) result |= (1UL<<i);
  }

  // Stop pulse
  while(digitalRead(receive_pin) != HIGH);

  return result;
} 
    
void loop() {

  if (receiveIR() == remote_button_code){
    
    led_state^=1;
    digitalWrite(led_pin, led_state);

  };

}
```

My problem with this code, however, is on the line `while(digitalRead(receive_pin) != LOW)` (and I think in the line `while(digitalRead(receive_pin) != HIGH)`), it sticks the code in a loop until it receives a signal from the remote. This means I can not really use anything after the function `receiveIR()`, because once the code starts executing this function, it will only exit once a signal is received.

My workaround that is to put everything I want to run inside the

```
while(digitalRead(receive_pin) != LOW){
  }
```

in the `receiveIR()` function. Like so:

(this code uses a Sliding Switch to also control the LED)

```
#define led_pin 9
#define receive_pin 4
#define switch_pin 7

bool led_state = LOW;
bool switch_state;

unsigned long int remote_button_code = 835585799;

void setup() {

  pinMode(receive_pin, INPUT);
  pinMode(switch_pin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(led_pin,OUTPUT);
  switch_state = digitalRead(switch_pin);
}

unsigned long int receiveIR() {
  // Wait for start pulse
  while(digitalRead(receive_pin) != LOW){
    
    if(switch_changed()){
    
      led_state^=1;
      digitalWrite(led_pin, led_state);
    
    }

  }

  if(pulseIn(receive_pin, HIGH, 20000) == 0) return 0;

  // Receive pulses
  unsigned long int result = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    int pulseLength = pulseIn(receive_pin, HIGH, 5000);
    if(pulseLength == 0) return 0;
    if(pulseLength > 1000) result |= (1UL<<i);
  }

  // Stop pulse
  while(digitalRead(receive_pin) != HIGH);

  return result;
} 

bool switch_changed(){

  if (digitalRead(switch_pin) != switch_state){

    switch_state ^=1;

    return true; 
  }

    return false;

}

void loop() {

  if (receiveIR() == remote_button_code){
    
    led_state^=1;
    digitalWrite(led_pin, led_state);

  };

}
```

This workaround does the job, but it is not very elegant. Is there a way to modify the first code, so I can use other functions after I call the `receiveIR()` function?

Comment: move first two lines of receiveIR() into loop() ... do not use `while`, use `if` .... use a flag like `signalStarted = true` to "remember" if receive_pin has detected signal ...  something like this inside loop() ... the `if` statements are not nested ... if signal is detected and flag is not set, then set flag and start timer .... if flag is set and timer expired, then run receiveIR() ... do other stuff in loop()

Comment: forgot one test at the begining of loop() ... if signal not detected  then clear flag ... the `if` statement order does not really matter